# Record methods in TdwsUnit

Tags: delphi, dwscript

Is there a way to add methods to records in a TdwsUnit? It seems the members property only allows you to add fields. And is it possible to register constructors as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, the TdwsRecord.DoGenerate method doesn't support them yet...

Record constructors aren't supported at the moment, I'm considering reserving the syntax for true constructors (ala C++), you can achieve Delphi-like record constructor by using class functions (though due to the above limitation, they can currently only be declared in script code).